# Wrong background color ListView row in adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm trying to get a different color for every other row

If I scroll too fast then I might get 3 white rows in a row (no pun intended lol)

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Enlevement> {
      private final Activity context;
      private boolean shouldCreateGreyBackground = false;

      static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public LinearLayout layout;
      }

      public TestAdapter(Activity context ) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.context = context;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView;

          LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_enlevement_grey, null);

          ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

          viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.enlevementDate);
          viewHolder.layout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.layoutEnlevementItemGrey);

          rowView.setTag(viewHolder);


        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        Enlevement entry = getItem(position);
        holder.text.setText(String.valueOf(entry.i));
        if(shouldCreateGreyBackground){
            holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_listview_grey);
            shouldCreateGreyBackground = false;
        }
        else{
            holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_listview_white);
            shouldCreateGreyBackground = true;
        }


        return rowView;
      }
    }
```

I've tried several fixes and approaches to this bt with no luck.
any ideas?

Comment: instead of using the boolean you can use `if(position%2==0)//show grey else //show white`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(position%2 == 0){
    holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_listview_grey);
}
else{
    holder.layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_listview_white);
}
```

Comment: Damn I hate it when you realise the answer was obvious lol
thanks though!

Comment: ya like artists we have the `programers block`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (position%2 == 0) {
     view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

} else {
     view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```